# Can not delete whole string in JFormatedTextfield when using NumberFormatter

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, number-formatting

I've developed a GUI for a image editor project for university course. It's core functions are all there but I fell like I should restrict user (TA at OOP advanced course most likely) to only enter value 0-255 in the text field even though I do have methods within my custom Pixel class such as setRed(short red) that grantee that method parameter will be fixed on 255 if it is greater than it (analogously goes for zero value).

```
public void setRed (short newRed)
        {
            if(newRed>MAX_PIXEL_VALUE)
                this.red=MAX_PIXEL_VALUE;
            else if (newRed<MIN_PIXEL_VALUE)
                this.red=MIN_PIXEL_VALUE;
            else
                this.red=newRed;
        }
```

with constants having having these values:

```
private static final short MIN_PIXEL_VALUE = 0;
private static final short MAX_PIXEL_VALUE = 255;

private static final short MIN_TRANSPARENCY = 255;
private static final short MAX_TRANSPARENCY = 0;
```

Most of the components are from the AWT package (covered in OOP Java course) and text fields that take RGB inputs for selection coloring and Alpha field for layer transparency adjustment are JFormatedTextFields which are created with this NumberFormater:

```
 private NumberFormatter rgbaFormater()
{

    NumberFormat rgbaFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    rgbaFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(0);
    rgbaFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(3);
    
    NumberFormatter rgbaFormater = new NumberFormatter(rgbaFormat) ;
    rgbaFormater.setValueClass(Integer.class);
    rgbaFormater.setMinimum(0);
    rgbaFormater.setMaximum(255);
    rgbaFormater.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    rgbaFormater.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
    
    return  rgbaFormater;
    
}
```

Problem occurs when I can't erase the whole inputed string as shown when I typed in 255 and 2 can not be erased. I can only change its value by selecting it with a mouse and typing over it. How can I fix this?
[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!